# C++ instantiation via pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, instantiation

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class form{
public:
    form(int c ){
        code = c;
    }
    int code;
};
void createForm(form* f,int c){
    f = new Form(c);
}
int main(){
    form* f1;
    form* f2;
    createForm(f1,1111);
    createForm(f2,2222);
    cout<<f1->code<<endl;
    cout<<f2->code<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As a result,I didn't see anything printed out. 
I know that f1 & f2 are not created actually. So I'm wondering 
**if I can instantiate a class like this? If yes, then how ?**

Comment: Unless you have a need to, you can just use `form f1(1111);` and totally avoid pointers and dynamic memory.

Comment: I'm doing this because I need to instantiate many 'forms' and at the meantime, put'em into a pool for future use. Of course I can do: f1 = new form(1111); pool.push_back(f1); Then I'll have to write these 2 lines for EVERY instance. Dynamic memory has always been one of my biggest concern but I don't know how to avoid them for now. There's so much I have to learn :p THANK YOU !

Comment: `pool.push_back(form(1111));`

Comment: yeah,that's right. but I have to reference those forms from outside,so putting it into the pool is not the only purpose,I have to instantiate the EXACT form f1 and then put it into pool.So when I do container->f1 I can get f1,when I search for some_form->code=f2->code from pool,I can get f2. You have any good approach for this ?

Comment: `vector<unique_ptr<form>>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void createForm(form* f,int c){
    f = new Form(c);
}
```

will create an object and assign its address to the local `f` - which is a copy of the original `f1` and `f2` withing that function's scope.

The original pointers are left unchanged, so the following `cout<<` statements lead to undefined behavior.

What you're trying to achieve can be accomplished by passing the pointer by reference:

```
createForm(form*& f,int c)
```

You also forgot to call `delete`, so now you have a memory leak.

Even better - don't use pointers at all.

Comment: Arguably, `form* createForm(int c) { return new Form(c); }` is even more intuitive to use: `form* f1 { createForm(1111) };` / `f2 = createForm(2222);` etc..

Comment: "Event better - don't use pointers at all"

Do no say that. In C++, we can pass data with reference, but pointers are still useful.
eg. When declaring a class, always put pointers on object instead of full object.
It avoids having a big block of allocated datas, since pointers only takes 4 bytes in memory.
Its better to have an object with 3 pointers (which weight 12 bytes in memory) than a object with 3 objects in it (which can weight hundred of bytes, depending on the objects themselves)

Comment: @Larta The comment needs to be taken in context. Luchian meant that you should avoid dynamically allocating memory (i.e., with a pointer) unless you need to.

Comment: @Larta the hunderd-of-bytes big objects still have to be somewhere, right?

Comment: Yep, but what i meant to say is that it's better to have small blocks of data than a big ones.
(XX_X______XX__XX________XXXXXXX is better than XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX___XX. Just a matter of memory access time and memory optimization)
Anyway, it's something unnoticable in fact, and people just don't have to know it when developing.
And to be more precise, in my example, there's 3 big objects. They'll be spared in the memory, rather than next to each other, making one even bigger object, hard to put in memory for the system. That could tend to segfault, in another tiny world)

Comment: @Larta this is secondary to ownership. The alternative to have pointers is having raw pointers, if pointers is what you really need. But pointers to object signify a loose relationship. Having an object directly in the class signifies ownership. This is a design decision that shouldn't be taken based on whether you think fragmentation or access time is a problem. Besides, IDK why you make that assumption - it's not better to have small blocks because the cache would be sparse. Having bigger blocks grouped together should put less strain on the cache and prevent fragmentation.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the pointer by reference.

```
void createForm(form* &f,int c){
    f = new Form(c);
}
```

However, I would rather change the `createForm` function to look like this:

```
form* createForm(int c) {
   return new Form(c);
}
```